# ffmpeg - overlay multiple fading texts with different colors

Tags: ffmpeg

I have problem with this ffmpeg command, it works fine if the fading text is in white font color, but if I change the fontcolor to something else (for example black), the fading text will not appear, any ideas?

```
ffmpeg -i ./based_video/480/clip3.mp4 -filter_complex "color=black:100x100[c]; [c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv0]; \
[ct]setsar=1,split=3[t1][t2][t3]; \
[t1]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf:text='\$30,000.0':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white,split[text1][alpha1]; \
[text1][alpha1]alphamerge,fade=t=in:st=1:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1:alpha=1[txta1]; \
[t2]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf:text='\$30,000.0':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white,split[text2][alpha2]; \
[text2][alpha2]alphamerge,fade=t=in:st=1:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1:alpha=1[txta2]; \
[t3]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf:text='\$30,000.0':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white,split[text3][alpha3]; \
[text3][alpha3]alphamerge,fade=t=in:st=1:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1:alpha=1[txta3]; \
[mv0][txta1]overlay=x='100':y='200':shortest=1[mv1]; \
[mv1][txta2]overlay=x='300':y='200':shortest=1[mv2]; \
[mv2][txta3]overlay=x='500':y='200':shortest=1" \
-c:v libx264 -c:a copy ./output_video/testnew-clip3-output.mp4
```

full log is here : 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y9Dnn0Df75J8P_hZ6LjHTX2dk-8z97UnTjlX8dnc0v0/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're feeding the plane with the drawn text as the alpha. If the text is black, then the alpha is black and so the text won't appear. You can skip the alpha creation and merging altogether.

```
ffmpeg -i ./based_video/480/clip3.mp4 -filter_complex "color=black@0:100x100,format=yuva444p[c]; [c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv0]; \
[ct]setsar=1,split=3[t1][t2][t3]; \
[t1]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf:text='\$30,000.0':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white,fade=t=in:st=1:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1:alpha=1[txta1]; \
[t2]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf:text='\$30,000.0':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white,fade=t=in:st=1:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1:alpha=1[txta2]; \
[t3]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf:text='\$30,000.0':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white,fade=t=in:st=1:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1:alpha=1[txta3]; \
[mv0][txta1]overlay=x='100':y='200':shortest=1[mv1]; \
[mv1][txta2]overlay=x='300':y='200':shortest=1[mv2]; \
[mv2][txta3]overlay=x='500':y='200':shortest=1" \
-c:v libx264 -c:a copy ./output_video/testnew-clip3-output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks Mulvya for your answer, but weird thing is, after I tried with your command, now even the white fading text doesn't appear, do you know why?

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: You're using a very old version where drawing text on transparent canvas isn't supported. DIdn't you upgrade a couple of days ago?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works if I run it on latest ffmpeg build. Sorry I was testing it on on my other machine which have older version of ffmpeg. Thanks again @Mulvya